# jQuery issue within Angular 4 when using ng2 materialize

Tags: jquery, angular, animation, select, materialize

https://sherweb.github.io/ng2-materialize/home  <--- This is where I found the tutorial.

Hi all.  I am dealing with a doozie. The worst kind of problem... one that once worked and now doesn't.  So I know it can work... it just isn't right now.  I am trying to use materialize css within my angular 4 app.  To really understand the issue, I simply started a new project right before going through the detailed tutorial.  Then, once installed and seemingly working, I try to place a select HTML field in my `user.module.ts`.  The page will load okay, but then an error arises when I click outside of the select to make the options disappear.

I have a feeling my issue is improper placement of imports within the modules.  From their descriptions starting at Animation and ending after Usage, I have no idea or not enough of an idea which module the teacher is referring to place the imports.  My understanding is the Animations section need to go in the `app.module.ts` and that the Browser Animations Module needs to go into the module that will be taking advantage of the materialize.

Below is how I interpreted the instructions.  Then below that is the error I receive when trying to use select HTML tag.  Thanks for looking!

**.angular-cli.json**

```
  {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "rock-radar-front"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
          "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css",
          "../node_modules/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
  "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

**tsconfig**

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": [
      "jquery",
      "materialize-css"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
 ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**user.module.ts (user module is in user component inside the app folder)**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MaterializeModule } from 'ng2-materialize';
import { UserComponent } from "./user.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MaterializeModule
  ],
  declarations: [UserComponent]
})
export class UserModule { }
```

**Finally hear is the error I'm getting.  If I move imports around I can get different errors but in its current state I think its telling me it can't even recognize the imports.  Please let me know if you can see where I'm goofing! THANKS**

```
compiler.es5.js:1690 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'label' since it isn't a known property of 'select'. ("
  <select multiple mz-select
    id="options-select"
    [ERROR ->][label]="'Label'"
    [placeholder]="'Placeholder'"
  >
"): ng:///AppModule/UserComponent.html@3:4
Can't bind to 'placeholder' since it isn't a known property of 'select'. ("
    id="options-select"
    [label]="'Label'"
    [ERROR ->][placeholder]="'Placeholder'"
  >
    <optgroup label="Group 1">
"): ng:///AppModule/UserComponent.html@4:4
'mz-select-container' is not a known element:
1. If 'mz-select-container' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mz-select-container' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<mz-select-container>
  <select multiple mz-select
    id="options-select"
"): ng:///AppModule/UserComponent.html@0:0
        at syntaxError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:24056:34)
    at 
  TemplateParser.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler
/@angular/compiler.es5.js.TemplateParser.parse 
(http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:35176:19)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@
angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate 
(http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:49328:39)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:49248:62
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at 
  JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/
    @angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents 
(http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:49248:19)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:49135:19
    at Object.then (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:24045:156)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.
es5.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents
 (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:49134:26)
    at 
 JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/
compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync 
(http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:49063:37)
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere the step of including the js in the `.angular-cli.json` that is mentioned in the link you provided? Did you include that? You have labelled what looks like the `user.module` as that instead

Comment: thank you.  Sorry!  I fixed the provided code including my actual angualr.cli.json file.  So to answer your question, I believe I am including the .js.  Would you agree?

Comment: Looks good now yep, you are missing `.forRoot()` on the import in `UserModule` as well. And can you double check that you remembered `npm install` for each of the dependencies?

Comment: Yea I took off that '.forRoot()' part as I saw someone in another forum suggest it for what looked like a similar issue.  I put it back on.  But its still failing. But to your second question, no I did not do that... I hope.  I don't really understand what your mean.  What and in what directory do I need to npm install?

Comment: I am simply taking this from the article you linked - one of the first headings `Installation` (those `npm install` commands should be run from the root of your directory), you'll need both as you have included both in your `.angular-cli.json`

Comment: oh yea... I ran both of those.  I did everything in the instructions verbatim

Comment: anyone? ugh.  why me code god? why me

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to a web extension I had in chrome.  I hate when that turns out to be the issue.... sorry folks